# Find get the files I want,the pipe to xargs and Tar don't

Tags: linux, find, tar, xargs

I'm using the following command line:

```
find . -mtime -15 -mtime 0  -print0 | xargs -0  tar cjvf /home/user/adjuntos.tar.bz2
```

The left side of the pipe works like a charm, but the right side of the pipe grab all the files from the directory.

I don't know what I am doing wrong. Can you help me, please?

Answer (score 2):

Your `find` command likely lists `.` as well (`mtime` of `.` being possibly the same as the most recently modified file), which causes current directory be included by tar.

If you want to include only regular files and not directories, you could use `-type f` with `find`.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the `-type f`, no need for `xargs`, a plain `-exec` works just as well:

```
find . -mtime -15 -mtime 0  -exec tar cjvf /home/user/adjuntos.tar.bz2 {} +
```

(the `{} +` means "all the matching files together")

###### Note:

- Whether you use `find -exec {}+` or `find | xargs`, there is a limit on the arguments that are processed by a single command (use `xargs --show-limits` to check): about 2Mbytes on my Linux, 10K files with a 200-bytes average path length.
- If the total length of your files list exceeds this limit, both `find` and `xargs` will chop the arguments list into smaller pieces and invoke the command several times
- `tar -cf` **overwrites the file**: if it is invoked several times, the final archive will only contain the files from the last invocation.
- To obtain a complete archive you have to use `tar -r` so that the invocations append to the existing archive instead of overwriting it (and of course you have to erase the archive if it exists before you start), but you cannot use `-r` with compressed archives.